# Declaration Error: Identifier already declared

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm having a problem declaring the enum Stage.

The previous declaration is here:

```
enum stage {Init, Reg, Vote, Done}
```

Changing the Stage name doesn't help:

```
enum stage {Init, Reg, Vote, Done}
Stage public stage = Stage.Init;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change either the name of the enum or the name of the public property of Stage type.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of naming convention, you would normally use capitalised words for your enum declarations and mixed case for variables.

This [Solidity guideline](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/style-guide.html#naming-styles) will help you.

As per your specific case:

```
enum Stage {Init, Reg, Vote, Done}

Stage public stage = Stage.Init;
```